# How to CamelCase an string value even if string separator is null?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I need to convert a given string value (with or without separator) into a `CamelCase` string. So far this is what I am doing:

```
class UtilString
{
    public function stringToCamelCase($string, $character = null)
    {
        return preg_replace_callback("/{$character}[a-zA-Z]/", 'removeCharacterAndCapitalize', $string);
    }

    private function removeCharacterAndCapitalize($matches)
    {
        return strtoupper($matches[0][1]);
    }
}

$str1 = 'string_with_separator';
$str2 = 'string';

$test1 = (new UtilString())->stringToCamelCase($str1, '_'); 
$test2 = (new UtilString())->stringToCamelCase($str2);
```

Having the code above the outputs are:

```
$test1 = 'string_with_separator'; 
$test2 = 'string';
```

I want them to be:

```
$test1 = 'StringWithSeparator'; 
$test2 = 'String';
```

How? What I am doing wrong and how to fix it? I am using PHP 5.5.x!

**NOTE:** if you know any string manipulation class|package with this type of function please let me know so I am not reinventing the wheel!

Comment: What does `stringwithoutseparator` become?

Comment: @chris85 that one enter on the same path as `$str2` and the output should be `Stringwithoutseparator`

Comment: it mostly works except the first letter, but you're not checking for errors because your callback should be referenced like `[$this,'removeCharacterAndCapitalize']`

Comment: I'd just like to chime in and say that your method is creating StudlyCase or PascalCase versus camelCase (look, I know that camel's hold their head up naturally -- I'm just explaining the usages that I've encountered while being a professional developer).  Other terms in the realm of condensed-word formatting are: snake_case and kebab-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
class UtilString
{
    public function stringToCamelCase($string, $character = null)
    {
        $re = $character == null ? '/^([a-zA-Z])/' : '/(?:^|' . $character . ')([a-zA-Z])/';
        return preg_replace_callback($re, array('UtilString', 'removeCharacterAndCapitalize'), $string);
    }

    private function removeCharacterAndCapitalize($matches)
    {
        return strtoupper($matches[1]);
    }
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/yW84DE)

Since you need to account for an optional element, you need to use appropriate patterns for both scenarios. `$re = $character == null ? '/^([a-zA-Z])/' : '/(?:^|' . $character . ')([a-zA-Z])/';` will specify the first `/^([a-zA-Z])/` regex in case the `$char` is not passed. The second will match at the `$char` and at the beginning of the string. Both should have the capturing group to be able to change the case and return the proper string inside `removeCharacterAndCapitalize`.

And  as for using a callback itself in your class, you need to check [*preg_replace_callback requires argument 2 to be a valid callback… Stuck!*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530026/preg-replace-callback-requires-argument-2-to-be-a-valid-callback-stuck). It must be defined as `array('UtilString', 'removeCharacterAndCapitalize')` in the `preg_replace_callback`.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function called [`ucwords()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) that uppercases the first character of every word. It takes a second parameter for the delimiters.

Note that `ucwords()` does **not** remove the delimiters. So you need to do this by yourself, e.g. with `str_replace`. Here is a simple example:

```
function stringToCamelCase($string) {

    $delimiters = array('_');

    $string = ucwords($string, implode('', $delimiters));
    $string = str_replace($delimiters, '', $string);

    return $string;
}

$my_string = 'string_with_separator';
echo stringToCamelCase($my_string);
```

Output:

```
StringWithSeparator
```